# Which design is a better? A singleton object or pass an object everytime?

Tags: oop, object, architecture

I have a view, controller and model. which is a desktop application, let say it is a browser. So, there have an object called AppCurrentStatus. Which contain the windows position, how many window is opening, and the window content.

So, let say, user wanna to open a new tab, and the flow is work like this:

```
1. View (user interface) press new a tab.
2. Fire event to controller.
3. Controller update the AppCurrentStatus, add one new tab.
4. Controller notify the model, the model store the data, just in case the user close the browser incidentally
```

The question is, how the view, controller and model get the information they need from AppCurrentStatus? Should I make the AppCurrentStatus become a singleton, that allow everyone can call it. For example, the user can have more than 3 tabs, and the controller can call it directly via a singleton, to check whether it have 3 tabs or not. If new tab is successfully added, will can the model save the AppCurrentStatus with in asking the controller, just call it from singleton.

Another approach is keeping the AppCurrentStatus as a variable in the controller, when user add a new tab, the event will fire and tell the controller check it self's AppCurrentStatus, if it is modify, just pass this object to model, to save it.

More specify to tell the different, the model will like this, approach one:

```
-(void)save(); //calling singleton
```

if approach two is something like this

```
-(void)save(AppCurrentStatus aAppCurrentStatus); //save from a object
```

or other better solutions can be suggested?

Answer (score 2):

I find that I often start of my code with a singleton. Even though I know better - singletons like this are basically globals, and we all know globals are bad.

But, it is so darn *easy* to code up a singleton like this, and use it wherever necessary.

Often, in a little while - a month or so - I end up switching to the "pass it around" pattern.  Usually because what started out as a singleton becomes more than one.  E.g. in the stuff I do for a living, a singleton processor_under_test() becomes multiple processors.

In your case, ask yourself: what is the chance that your single App, reflected in AppCurrentStatus, will eventually become one of a set of several cooperating apps?  If low, the singleton may be the easy way.

(In a related vein, think about how many single document apps become multiple documents.)

Don't worry yourself about this, about finding the best possible way.  Changes like this are just part of programming. Sometimes you flow from singleton to, what could we call it, N-ton. Sometimes back.

However, it is worth mentioning two related patterns here.

First, when what started out as a singleton becomes an N-ary-ton, you don't need to give up the ease of use of a global singletin right away. Instead, you can create a master singleton, which I usually call something like "environ", that holds the several N-ary-ton objects or references, and probably other stuff besides.

Also, if you do choose to pass the object around, you don't necessarily need to pass just the AppCurrentStatus around.  Because you will probably eventually need to pass something else as well.  Again, I usually pass around something I call an Environmrnt, whivch may have different shapes at different call sites.

---

Two final notes:

(1) I am willing to tolerate the use of singletons in application code that is not a good candidate for reuse.  However, I have found that if I am writing code that is likely ever to want to be included in a library and reused elsewhere, then depending on a singleton is bad - because that elsewhere may not want to clutter itself with your singleton(s).

Similarly, for some reason I have found it harder to write good unit tests for singleton code.  I can't remember all of the details right now, but, consider: how do you test several differeht ways of constructing and destructing a singleton?  And you may well want a destructor or finalizer, if for no other reason than when your app shuts down.

For these reasons, I often create two classes:

The inner class, which in your example I might call AppCurrentStatus.
And the outer class, AppCurrentStatus_singleton.

Possibly hiding the implementation of the inner class from people who will be using the singleton, but exposing it so that you can write a good set of unit tests. I do this often enough that in C++ I have created some templates that do the easy cases:  Singleton.

(2) Finally, in case you care about performance, the more parameters that get passed around, the slower.  Whereas the singleton global is probably faster.

For most programs this is probably a don't care, premature optimization.  I just think about that sort of thing since performance is my bread and butter.

Related, maintainability: although singletons are globals, and globals are bad, I think that big argument lists for functions/methods are even worse.  I'd rather use singletons.  But the Paramater Object desiogn pattern may be better.

---

OK, I lied: another issue in favor of singletons:  sometimes you don't have the ability to change all of the code.  E.g. sometimes you pass a callback to some library, who eventually calls your code. You may not have the option of adding a parameter to this interface. A singleton can do this.

Related: anyone doing callbacks should provide an escape hatch: a generic object reference, or a cookie, that the callback manipulating library passes around, but does not impute semantics to.

Answer (score 0):

The question conflates two different concepts: *singleton* and *static class*.

Using a static class will work -- all of the state data is stored statically, and can be accessed from anywhere. Since your question also emphasizes object-oriented principles, though, I will suggest that this is not the favoured approach, as it constrains your future development. Static classes do not lend themselves to dependency injection or being mocked or decorated.

A singleton implementation is often frowned upon, but offers a good solution to your case -- it is the best of both worlds insofar as you pass around variables, but they all point to the same, single object. This way you can still use decorators or mock the component if you want to create unit tests, but all controllers ultimately reference and have access to the same status information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a factory method to get an instance of the AppCurrentStatus value and call it each time you need to access it.

```
AppCurrentStatusHolder.getAppCurrentStatus()
```

Now in the beggining you can use a singleton but later if you need to change the strategy then  you are less coupled with the implementation.